# Reference associated type in trait bounds

Tags: rust

I have a trait which is meant to tighten constraints on another trait, e.g.:

```rust
trait AssocA {}
trait AssocB: AssocA {}
trait A { type MyAssoc: AssocA; }
trait B: A { type MyAssoc: AssocB; }
```

If I were using generics rather than associated types, I'd be able to tell Rust that `MyAssoc` is the same across traits `A` and `B`:

```rust
trait AssocA {}
trait AssocB: AssocA {}
trait A<MyAssoc> where MyAssoc: AssocA {}
trait B<MyAssoc>: A<MyAssoc> where MyAssoc: AssocB { }
```

How can I do the same with associated types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the implementing type via `Self` and since `B: A`, `Self::MyAssoc` already exists.

```
trait B: A where Self::MyAssoc : AssocB {}
```

This prohibits `impl B for T {}` when `<T as A>::MyAssoc` does not implement `AssocB`. [(example)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=27a783f2de89c2400ddc&version=stable)